# Is it possible to use pattern matching guards in a `while let`?

Tags: while-loop, pattern-matching, rust

I have a `while let` loop which goes over an iterator of `Result` and uses pattern matching; it goes over the iterator until it either hits an `Err` or the `Ok`'s value is an empty string:

```
while let Some(Ok(a)) = some_iterator.next() {
    if a == "" {
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

This code works fine. However, I think the `if` statement looks ugly and is probably not idiomatic Rust. In `match` statements, guards can be used in pattern matching, like so:

```
match foo {
    Some(Ok(a)) if a != "" => bar(a)
    // ...
}
```

This would be ideal for my `while let` loop, although the pattern matching employed there doesn't seem to support it, causing a syntax error:

```
while let Some(Ok(a)) = some_iterator.next() if a != "" { // <-- Syntax error
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way of using guards like this in the condition of a `while let`? If not, is there a better way of breaking out of the loop if an empty string is found?

Comment: *and is probably not idiomatic Rust* — FWIW, I've written code like that; doesn't seem bad to me.

Comment: I'd encourage answerers to focus on answering the *primary* question (guards in a `while let`). OP [should probably ask another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829) for the "is there a better way" aspect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, `while let` and `if let` patterns cannot have guards. There has been some discussion about changing that (e.g. [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/935)), but nothing has been decided yet.

Regarding alternatives, I think your version is pretty clear and I can't think of any ways to really improve on that.

Answer (score 3):

To those that find this from a web search, here's the `if-let-chains` RFC that addresses conditions in `if let` expressions:

https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2497-if-let-chains.html

Comment: And so this is now in the language, and the original answer, while correct at the time, no longer is?  You can now do what they want?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Not yet, it's still an unstable feature, which means still in development and not usable without the nightly compiler and a feature flag.

Comment: I literally just went over to https://play.rust-lang.org and discovered this myself, but thanks for the confirmation.  Compiler help says ` add `#![feature(let_chains)]` to the crate attributes to enable` on nightly.  [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667) for it.

Answer (score 1):

For all intents and purposes, your code is the most legible.

But you can get creative (including with tools which weren't available at the time of asking).

Cramming a condition into a pattern match :

```rust
while let (Some(a), true) = (iterator.next(), independent_condition()) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Putting the filter inside the iterator :

```rust
while let Some(a) = iterator.take_while(|a| a!= "").next() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Keeping in mind that in simple cases when you end up with a single iterator which does not depend on things you borrow inside the loop, you no longer need while and a Some pattern de-structuring :

```rust
for a in iterator.take_while(|a| a!= "") {
    //do stuff
}
```

skip_while and scan are similar advanced method on iterator which may come in handy in these kind of situations.